# Symfony is throwing a "Make sure there is a loader supporting the "/config/config_dev.yml" type" error?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I've had an application I built a year ago in Symfony 3.4 that I need to use again briefly but, when I checked it out and tried to run it I got the error:

```
Cannot load resouce "<folder_path_here>". Make sure there is a loader supporting the "/config/config_dev.yml" type
```

Having not had this before and having looked for any information on what might be causing it, I'm still none the wiser.

My config_dev.yml file for reference:

```
imports:
  - { resource: config.yml }

monolog:
  handlers:
    main:
      type: stream
      path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
      level: info
    console:
      type: console
      bubble: false
```

And my AppKernel.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Checkout\Checkout()
        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function getRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__;
    }

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__) . '/var/cache/' . $this->getEnvironment();
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__) . '/var/logs';
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__, '/config/config_' . $this->getEnvironment() . '.yml');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore me. I'm an idiot. There's a typo in registerContainerConfiguration. A ',' instead of a '.' ._.